# Why can't I ping my Linux VM from WAN?

Tags: debian, networking, ping

My overarching goal is to get a website and custom-built server live running on a box I have in my basement. This is a learning exercise for me.

So, I have debian installed on a VM, in bridge mode. Although this apparently doesn't matter, I have ports 22 and 80 forwarded to the VM and I verified with my ISP that these ports are open. I only mention it because ssh doesn't seem to be working either.

When I try to ping it, it sends the packets but it receives no response. I am stuck. I'm also somewhat new to linux. That is to say, I've only done school programming projects on it. I can't find an answer that works for me, at least not yet.

Recap: running VM in bridged mode, to which the router assigns a static ip. On the external computer, I type $ ping debianserver@. When I just try to ping just the public ipv6 address, the router refuses the connection, but when I try with the name of the computer (debianserver), it sends packets but does not receive any.

Thanks for your time and help in advance!

Comment: Are you able to ping from the VM to the computer that you have been trying to ping from or are you able to ping the router from either the VM or the computer it is running on?
Is the VM able to connect to the internet? Are both devices on the same network with the same subnet mask? If not is the router set to forwarding packets to the other network? Edit
If you are unable to ping your public IP address it sounds more like it is to do with your router

Comment: A private IP address does not ping from the Internet. As for the public IP address, does it start with fe:80?

Comment: I can ping from the OS hosting the VM, yes, using its private ipv4. The public ipv6 starts with fea6. I do not get a response pinging the other computer from the VM OS.

Comment: Just to add--for some reason I no longer get assigned a public ipv4 after trying to forward port 80 and 22 and switching routers and trying to forward port 80 and 22 again (I am also trying to ssh and host a public node server).

Answer (score 0):

The ping/ICMP packets are most likely being filtered/dropped by the firewall on your cable modem/DSL modem/whatever.  If you want pings/ICMP to that server to work from the WAN, you will need to see if your modem allows you to designate your server as a DMZ device.  Some ISPs don't allow this in their modems.  If you can, then ALL traffic destined for your external IP address will be forwarded to your server.  In other words, you wouldn't need to specifically create port-forward rules for SSH/22, HTTP/80, HTTPS/443.  Please note, I've never seen a cable/DSL modem capable of doing a ping/ICMP port-forward.

We could provide more specific information if you told us which ISP your using, and the model/type of modem you're using.